# Why do *args and **kwargs seem to disappear in class decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

Practicing with decorators, found this behavior strange:

```
def test_decorator(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    print (args, kwargs)
    def build(*args, **kwargs):
        print (args, kwargs)
        return cls(*args, **kwargs)
    return build

@test_decorator
class Test:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

t = Test(1, 2, 3, val = 4)
print (t.args, t.kwargs)

# output
# () { }
# (1, 2, 3) {'val' = 4}
# (1, 2, 3) {'val' = 4}
```

Why does the first `print` in the decorator show empty containers? Further, if I defined `build()` as:

```
def build():
    return cls(*args, **kwargs)
```

I know it will fail because of [nested function scoping](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example). I'm just not sure why they somehow don't exists before the call to `build` and suddenly return to scope.

Comment: They're *arguments* to build, the only thing passed to `test_decorator` is `cls`. It's not clear what you think has disappeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two different callables here:

- `test_decorator()`
- the wrapper returned by `test_decorator()`, `build()`.

You are confusing the two.

The first is called with *only the class*, because

```
@test_decorator
class Test:
    # ...
```

is really just

```
class Test:
    # ...
Test = test_decorator(Test)
```

That call is only passed *one argument*, the class being decorated, which is assigned to the `cls` name. The `args` and `kwargs` arguments to that call remain empty.

When you then call `Test(...)`, you are really calling `build(...)`. That call is passed arguments that are captured by the local `args` and `kwargs` objects, and passed to `cls(...)` (which references the original class object). Those arguments are not lost, they clearly are being passed on to the `__init__` method and the instance attributes by the same names are correctly set.

To distinguish the different catch-all parameters, start with giving them different names and augment your `print()` output:

```
def test_decorator(cls, *decorator_args, **decorator_kwargs):
    print('Decorator called with ({!r}, *{!r}, **{!r})'.format(
        cls, decorator_args, decorator_kwargs))
    def build(*build_args, **build_kwargs):
        print('build() wrapper called with (*{!r}, **{!r})'.format(
            build_args, build_kwargs))
        print('The decorator was originally called with ({!r}, *{!r}, **{!r})'.format(
            cls, decorator_args, decorator_kwargs))
        return cls(*build_args, **build_kwargs)
    return build
```

Now the output becomes:

```
>>> @test_decorator
... class Test:
...     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         self.args = args
...         self.kwargs = kwargs
...
Decorator called with (<class '__main__.Test'>, *(), **{})
>>> t = Test(1, 2, 3, val = 4)
build() wrapper called with (*(1, 2, 3), **{'val': 4})
The decorator was originally called with (<class '__main__.Test'>, *(), **{})
>>> t.args, t.kwargs
((1, 2, 3), {'val': 4})
```

Note that the *Decorator called with ...* output was produced when the `class` statement was executed, while the `t = Test(...)` call triggered the *build() wrapper called ...* output.

Comment: So does the class passed to the decorator retain its arguments?

Comment: @pstatix: yes, it does. You already saw this in your own output.

Comment: Very nice write-up; from this I suppose the convention is that each decorator has a single responsibility, meaning it should only have a single wrapper function inside?

Comment: @pstatix: not necessarily. A decorator is a very simple contract: The `@<something>` syntax above a function or class is called and the function or class is passed in. **Whatever** the decorator returns is assigned to the original name. You have a huge amount of flexibility beyond that contract.

Comment: @pstatix: the decorator could just return the original object. That's how many web frameworks (like Django and Flask) use decorators to register functions to handle requests: they update a registry with information and return the original function, otherwise untouched.

Comment: Pure lack of exposure to them I suppose; came up that the `@classmethod` would be good for something, started falling down the rabbit hole.

Comment: @pstatix: so defining multiple alternative wrapper functions and returning one of them based on decisions made by the decorator is perfectly acceptable too. Or you return different class objects, or choose between the original and a replacement. The world is your oyster!